# template and forward declaration

Tags: c++, templates

```
class VisitorBase;

template<typename R = void>
class BaseVisitable
{
public:
    typedef R RetType;
    virtual ~BaseVisitable() {}

    // Ok,only need forward-declaration of VisitorBase
    virtual R Accept(VisitorBase&) = 0; 
protected:
    template<typename T>
    static RetType AcceptImp(T& visited, VisitorBase& guest) // same as above
    {
        // there is neither forward-declaration nor definition of Visitor type,
        // how can it pass compilation？
        if (Visitor<T>* p = dynamic_cast<Visitor<T>*>(&guest)) 
        {
            return p->Visit(visited);
        }

        // Visitor<int> v; error
    }
};
```

This code is excerpted from LOKI.And i have some puzzled written in comment above.I can't  understand why the Vistor pointer don't need a forward-declaration but the object need.Thanks.

Comment: maybe there's `template <typename T> clas Visitor;` somewhere...

Comment: The excerpt fails to compile with "Visitor was not declared in this scope" It would appear that it *does* need forward declaration and the forward declaration exists somewhere else other than your excerpt.

Comment: Even when adding the forward declaration before the template definition, this doesn't explain why the first statement passes the build, but the `Visitor<int>` doesn't...

Comment: @EitanT why not? You can't instantiate incomplete types. But you can define pointers to incomplete types and manipulate those pointers.

Answer (score 0):

A forward declaration for `Visitor<T>` would not be enough, because a method of `Visitor<T>` is called by `p->Visit(visited)`, which means there has to be a declaration of `Visitor<T>` either by an include statement or a definition of `Visitor<T>` in the same file. Otherwise the compiler has no clue, that `Visitor<T>` has a member `Visit()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your excerpt is from the file `Visitor.h`. The excerpt does compile if you include the forward declaration `template<class T> class Visitor;` which **is** in that file.

Forward declaration of `Visitor` template is enough to call a function on `Visitor<T>` because it is a dependent type and the instantiation of `AcceptImp` template will instantiate the `Visitor<T>` template with the given type eventually. By then, `Visitor<T>` must have been defined (and the definition must also have the called function). If not, there will be a compile time error. If the `AcceptImp` template  is not instantiated at all, there will be no errors.

`Visitor<int>` is not a dependent type, so it must have been defined when `AcceptImp` is *defined* rather than when it's *insantiated*. Since `Visitor` is not defined, you cannot instantiate `Visitor<int>`.

Here's a simplified demo:

```
// forward declaration
template<class S>
struct Foo;

template<class T> 
void test(Foo<T>* f = nullptr) { // declaring a pointer is just fine
    if(f != nullptr)
        f->bar(); // calling a function is fine unless Foo<T> is incomplete or doesn't define bar
    // Foo<int> i; // oops, incomplete type, cannot do
    Foo<T> t; // Foo<T> must be complete when test<T> is instantiated, otherwise fails
}

// here's an example of what you can do
// let's define a specialization
template<>
struct Foo<int> {
    void bar(){}; // if we didn't define this, then we couldn't instantiate test<int>
};

// now you can instantiate Foo<int> and call test
int main() {
    Foo<int> i; // Foo<int> is a complete type now :)
    test(&i);
    // test<float>(); // oops, Foo<float> is incomplete
    //         test can't call Foo<float>::bar
    //         or instantiate an object of type Foo<float>
    //         Defining a pointer to Foo<T> in test would still be fine
}
```